# How to use the ShowcaseView library or something similar in a service?

Tags: java, android, service, floating

As I already wrote in the title, I'm searching for a way to display the [ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView//) in a service. The Service is displaying a floating widget like the facebook messenger chat head.`The problem is, that "MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)" is asking for an "android.app.Activity" attribute.

```
// single example
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(mButtonShow)
                .setDismissText("GOT IT")
                .setContentText("This is some amazing feature you should know about")
                .setDelay(withDelay) // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
                .singleUse(SHOWCASE_ID) // provide a unique ID used to ensure it is only shown once
                .show();
```

`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you explain more ? i didn't understand what's your problem ? you want to do the demo in a service ?!

Comment: Are you talking of floating widget like facebook messenger chat head ?

Comment: You can get context in service too.. Both Service and Activity are derived from Context class.

Comment: @ChintanSoni Yes, exactly a floating widget like the facebook messenger chat head.

Comment: @Fakher Yes, I wanted to do the demo in a Service, but I think that's actually not possible since the library requires some context form an Activity. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I ended up not using the [ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView//) in my Service, and implement another demo with simple TextViews myself.

This is how I do it now: 
I'm just showing some TextViews beside the buttons I want to introduce to the users. This is not like the ShowcaseView but it works perfectly for me.

Creating a TextView in a Floating Service:
(I set the TextView in the XML File to "INVISIBLE" to and after it is initialized to "GONE")

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

exampleTextLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.exampleTextLayout, null);
exampleTextView= (TextView) exampleTextLayout.findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);

WindowManager.LayoutParams textViewParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        textViewParam.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;

windowManager.addView(exampleTextLayout, textViewParam);
exampleTextLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And than later when I want to show the Text I do this:
(I skipped the animation part)

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams param_txt = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) layoutView.getLayoutParams();

param_txt.x = [xPosition of TextView]
param_txt.y = [yPosition of TextView]

if(layoutView.isAttachedToWindow()) {
      exampleTextLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      windowManager.updateViewLayout(exampleTextLayout, param_txt);
}
```

This is how it looks:
(Text is German if you wonder)

[image]

Comment: If Possible then please share that code that how you can create show case view using service

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya I'm just showing some TextViews at the right position beside the elements I want to introduce to the user. I'll update my post and will add some example code for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Tooleap](http://www.tooleap.com/) should help you.

[Here](http://developer.tooleap.com/api-guide/) you can find the guide related to how to use the library.

Comment: Thanks, but I already implement something similar. I only want to use the ShowcaseView with it.